# SimpleXML showing unexpected behaviour

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have a XML file named conf.xml and I'm trying to display the contents of this XML file via a simple php script (placed in the same directory) as follows:

**conf.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<registration_info>
  <organization name="Home" />
</registration_info>
```

**PHP script:**

```
$data=simplexml_load_file("conf.xml");
$node=$data->registration_info;
$subnode=$node->organization;
echo (string) $subnode['name']; // Displays null string
```

I feel that there's nothing wrong with the code but the output is unexpected as the anticipated output was "Home". Can anyone please help me solve this problem and explain me the solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must ignore the top level node (`registration_info` in this case).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Is it? Care to explain why?

Comment: I suppose it's a design decision (after all it's redundant since there always needs to be one and there can only be one) but I can only speculate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this hope this will help you out. You have to just remove `$node=$data->registration_info;`

[**Try this snippet here**](https://eval.in/783929)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$data=simplexml_load_file("conf.xml");
$subnode=$data->organization;
echo (string) $subnode['name'];
```

**Output:** `print_r($data)`

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [organization] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Home
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Can you please explain your solution?

Comment: Why did you neglect the registration_info node?

Comment: @hecate if you just look into my post which i have updated there is no key `registration_info`.

Comment: @hecate You were trying to access a keys which does not actually exists.

Comment: @hecate `registration_info` is a __root__ node of your xml. Creating xml object from `$data` implicitly hides your __root__ node and you can start working with object without accessing root node, but directly all chlid nodes.

Answer (score 2):

The existing answer given here is correct, but the explanations are rather confused. SimpleXML is not *hiding* the root node of your XML, it's just that the object you have *already is* that node.

Each `SimpleXMLElement` object represents a particular node in the XML document's tree. There is no separate object in SimpleXML representing "the whole document", so when you run `simplexml_load_file`, the object returned is the `SimpleXMLElement` for the root node.

```
$root_node = simplexml_load_file("conf.xml");
echo $root_node->getName(); // registration_info

$child_node = $root_node->organization;
// Short for $root_node->organization[0];
// meaning "get the first child with name 'organization'
echo $child_node->getName(); // organization
```